# Технология для мобильного приложения с доступом к камере

Tags: мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Какие есть современные технологии для создания мобильного приложения и главное чтобы был доступ к камере?Желательно чтобы можно было сразу написать под Андроид и Ios,а язык Python или JS.

Answer (score 0):

Самые популярные на сегодня инструменты для кроссплатформенной мобильной разработки это:

- [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Ionic](https://ionic.io/)
- [Sencha](https://www.sencha.com/)